# zmq make seems to be failing on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, makefile, zeromq, ubuntu-20.04

**Build and install ZeroMQ**

Previously zmq 4.3.2 was succesfully build on ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS but after upgrading ubuntu 22.04 LTS and zmq version to 4.3.4 installation seems to be failing.

**Environment**
libzmq version : v4.3.4
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy )
GCC : 12.0.1
G++ : 12.0.1
Make : 4.3

**Minimal test code / Steps to reproduce the issue**

1. Clone 4.3.4 source code
2. cd zeromq
3. ./autogen.sh
4. chmod +x configure
5. ./configure --prefix=/XXX/XXX --enable-shared --with-libsodium --disable-static --
   disable-werror --without-docs make -j8

### **What's the actual result?**

```
Making all in doc
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/zeromq/doc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/zeromq/doc'
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/zeromq'
  CXX      tools/curve_keygen.o
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-curve_client.lo
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-rep.lo
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-req.lo
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-router.lo
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-scatter.lo
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-select.lo
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-server.lo
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-session_base.lo
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-signaler.lo
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-socket_base.lo
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-socks.lo
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-socks_connecter.lo
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-stream.lo
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:535,
                 from src/err.hpp:39,
                 from src/msg.hpp:37,
                 from src/curve_client.cpp:35:
In function 'void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)',
    inlined from 'static int zmq::curve_client_tools_t::produce_initiate(void*, size_t, uint64_t, const uint8_t*, const uint8_t*, const uint8_t*, const uint8_t*, const uint8_t*, const uint8_t*, const uint8_t*, const uint8_t*, size_t)' at src/curve_client_tools.hpp:186:16:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:29:33: error: 'void* __builtin_memcpy(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)' offset [0, 79] is out of the bounds [0, 0] [-Werror=array-bounds]
   29 |   return __builtin___memcpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len,
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   30 |                                  __glibc_objsize0 (__dest));
      |                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
  CXX      src/libzmq_la-stream_connecter_base.lo
make[1]: *** [Makefile:5394: src/libzmq_la-curve_client.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/zeromq'
make: *** [Makefile:8216: all-recursive] Error 1
----------------------------------------
[ ERROR(2) ]
```

**What's the expected result?**

As steps mentioned in installation documents make shoud have been succesfull.